# Determine adjoint Operator in Hilbert space

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, adjoint-operators

Let $S:L^{2}((0,1))\to L^{2}((0,1))$ be such that $(Su)(x)=\displaystyle\int_{0}^{x}y\,u(y)\,\text{d}y$. Determine the adjoint operator $S^{*}$ in the sense that $\langle Su,v\rangle = \langle u,S^{*}v\rangle$ for all $u,v\in L^{2}((0,1))\\$

I tried to begin on the left of the equation and use Fubini, but I couldn't find out $S^{*}$. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proposed method is perfectly fine. You need change the order of the integrals:
$$ \langle Su, v \rangle = \int_0^1 dx \int_0^xdy \ y u(y) v(x) = \int_0^1 dy \int_y^1 dx  \ y u(y) v(x)  = \langle u, S^\star v\rangle.
$$
So
$$ (S^\star v)(y) = y\int_y^1 dx \ v(x). $$

Comment: Thank you very much.